# SAP HANA OBJECT PRIVILEGES VIEW

Tags: view, hana, privileges

I am currently searching for a table that contains all privileges that can be granted on a SAP HANA DB.

I was looking for a view similar to the V$OBJECT_PRIVILEGE on ORACLE DB.

Does it even exist?

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The V$OBJECT_PRIVILEGE covers only the privileges related to objects (e.g. 'CREATE SESSION' wouldn't be in there).

For SAP HANA you'll find all the possible privileges in the documentation, e.g. here http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/f674e1751910148a8b990d33efbdc5/content.htm

- Lars

Comment: SO, and answering my question, we cannot find a view on SAP HANA with all that information right? Like in Oracle DB...

Comment: Your question contains a false premise as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if really **all** privileges are listed here - but have a look at the [GRANTED_PRIVILEGES](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/a5958e751910149536e9ab4b54dd87/content.htm) system view.